# Transcribe bash to zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, colors, prompt, macos

I was wondering how could I write this:

```
export PS1="\[\033[38;5;51m\]\u\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]@\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;10m\]\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;226m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]\[\033[38;5;15m\]\\$\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

in zsh, specifically the colors. This came from my .bashrc file and I want to keep it for my .zshrc file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is this:

- Every occurrence of `\[\033[38;5;Nm\]` becomes simply `%NF`.
- Every occurrence of `\[$(tput sgr0)\]` becomes simply `%f`.
- `\u`, `\h`, `\w`, and `\$` become `%n`, `%m`, `%~`, and `%#`.

And make sure that you have the `PROMPT_PERCENT` shell option turned on.

You do not need to export this shell variable.

The manual that you should be reading is `zshmisc`.

Comment: Or `info zsh 'Prompt Expansion'`

Comment: also look at powerlevel10k and ohmyzsh, great answer @jdeBP